# Use of Tesseract for Text detection in Electronic Circuits

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm having trouble with text detection. I'm using tesseract on python to detect circuits' notes related to components (\Ohm, V, A, R_1, v_6, and so on)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvGDS.png)
The results I've obtained till now are not really good, because sometimes it is unable to detect test or in the worst case it detect the voltage generator for example as text[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFGB8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CDRp.png)
Is there a way to adjust this???
I'm going crazy about that.

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = cv2.imread('test.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray, 215, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite('a.png', binary_image)

custom_config = r'--psm 11 --oem 3'# -c       tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψ    ω'


text_boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(binary_image, config=custom_config)


result_image = image.copy()
text_boxes_coordinates = []

for box in text_boxes.splitlines():
    box = box.split()
    x, y, w, h = int(box[1]), int(box[2]), int(box[3]), int(box[4])
    text_box_coords = (x, y, w, h)

    text_boxes_coordinates.append(text_box_coords)

    cv2.rectangle(result_image, (x, image.shape[0] - y), (w, image.shape[0] - h), (255, 255, 255), -1)


cv2.imwrite('img_without_text.png', result_image)

image = Image.open('test.png')
background_image = Image.new("RGB", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
for box in text_boxes_coordinates:

    x, y, w, h = int(box[0]), int(box[1]), int(box[2]), int(box[3])

    component_image = image.crop((x,image.size[1]-h,w,image.size[1]-y))

    background_image.paste(component_image, (x,image.size[1]-h,w,image.size[1]-y))

background_image.save('only_text.png')
```

I tried to change multiple times the configuration parameters, without any successful result